# Reload doesn't add store and layer

Tags: geoserver

I have two geoservers:

A has 1 workspace, 1 store (postgis) and 1 layer.
B is empty.

I copy the full data_dir from A to B, and reload config on B. But after reload only the workspace shows on B, not the store or the layer. If I restart B the store and the layer shows up.

Am I correct in copying the full data_dir?

Am I missing a part somewhere?

Comment: I think that is as designed

Comment: Really? I'm trying to follow this guide: https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/educational/en/clustering/clustering/passive/passive.html#highly-available-ha-set-up-for-geoserver

Comment: I get the impression that copy and reload (as I do now) is the way to do it.